# What is the difference between never and void in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652), but it is unclear what would be the difference between 'never' and 'void' type?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In imperative languages, `void` can be thought of as a type containing a single value. Such languages do not provide a means to construct or consume this value, but a `void` function can be thought of as returning this trivial value.

In contrast `never` is a type containing no values, which means that a function with this return type can never return normally at all. This means either throwing an exception or failing to terminate.

Comment: Incorrect for `void` in most imperative languages. In those languages, `void` _is_ the bottom type, which has no value exactly (e.g. a function argument can't be of `void` type). The answer confuses bottom type with _unit type_.

Comment: @FrankHB - If that were true then functions with a `void` return type would never return at all, which is not necessarily the case. Calling a `void` function is a statement in these languages, and statements are mapped to expressions of type `unit` in expression-oriented languages like Rust, F# etc.

Comment: This is still false for those cases in C, C++, Java... Technically, statement is usually strictly distinct with expression (e.g. expression has no trailing ';' in those C-ish languages), and few languages allow expressions being reduced to statements. A statement formed by a function call expression is an "expression statement", which is forbidden to be a function argument syntactically. OTOH a function call expression can be syntactically correct argument, but disallowed by typechecking against `void`. It has nothing to do with termination property yet.

Comment: @FrankHB - First you said "In those languages, void is the bottom type", now you're saying is has nothing to do with termination. Which is it? It's not clear what your objection is.

Comment: Well, I'd reconstruct my words. The objection is to your first statement. As you have said, "in imperative languages", where the imperative languages should be the _object languages_ (like Typescript here). Your statement suggests the `void` type is allowed by rules of them as a real unit type, which is not the fact (e.g. in the case I gave). Moreover, treating `void` as a unit type does not make help at all (if not confusing), as long as you ignore how the implementations actually utilize the type.

Comment: Most of such languages (at least C-ish ones) has `void` as one of the static type, handled by the typechecker as mandatory. The violation shall be detected by typechecking on the ill-typed expressions. This has nothing to do with termination of called functions _in object languages_, even if it does make the translation (including typechecking) not terminate normally. The translation should terminate though, due to additional requirements of diagnostics rules. _Replacing_ `void` with a unit type in the translation to make it always terminate is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 53):

As [Marius Schulz discusses in this](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/the-never-type-in-typescript#the-difference-between-never-and-void) article,

> - A function that doesn't explicitly return a value **implicitly    returns** the value `undefined` in JavaScript. Although we typically say that such a function "doesn't return anything", it returns. We usually ignore the return value in these cases. Such a function is inferred to have a `void` return type in TypeScript.
> - A function that has a `never` return type never returns. **It doesn't return** `undefined`, either. The function doesn't have a normal completion,    which means it throws an error or never finishes running at all.

Comment: Thanks for this addition, this was the best answer for me

Comment: This is simple and to the point explanation of void return

Answer (score 33):

To augment Lee's very good answer, another way to think of it is that in a correctly-typed program, a `never` value *cannot* be observed.

In addition to functions which never return (or which always throw exceptions), you'll see the `never` type when a union type has been exhausted of all its possible constituents:

```
// Example assumes --strictNullChecks
function fn(x: number | string) {
  if (typeof x === 'number') {
    // x: number in this block
  } else if (typeof x === 'string') {
    // x: string in this block
  } else {
    // x: never in this block
    // this block does not run; the value of x cannot be observed
  }
}
```

Comment: "never value cannot be observed": I thought it is the same for 'void' value, no?

Comment: @ironic In theory they are distinct things. `void` is unit type, it has only one (quite useless) value. On the other hand `never` is bottom type. It has no value. The usefulness of this distinction between two seemingly same things is not always obvious and indeed in many situations one is interchangeable with the other for all practical purposes but a very sharp theoretical distinction does exist.

Comment: @ironic I can think of a somewhat intuitive example : a function that is called purely for its side effects and is not supposed to return any value (`print` for example) is of type `void`. It returns with the only value the type `void` can hold. You can do absolutely nothing interesting with that value. On the other hand if there is a function that is supposed to never return at all, then the intent is much better reflected by marking it as `never` rather than `void`

Comment: `void` isn't a unit type. The return value of a function reference whose return type is `void` can be anything because it's legal for a non-`void`-returning function to be aliased by a `void`-returning type.

Answer (score 32):

In short:

`void` returns `void`, `never` never returns.

Comment: You can't really "return void". It *means* it "doesn't return anything" but because JavaScript is JavaScript, what it actually returns is `undefined` *but* you shouldn't *use* that return value for anything, you should pretend like there isn't one.

Comment: @mpen FWIW, you can return void * actually. 'cause it's perfect safe to `return void  'any value here'`, and the returned value will always be `undefined`.
TS `() => void` is just a sugar on `() => undefined` and good boys don't use results from these functions.

Comment: @Ryuujo That's using void as an operator, not the type. If you have a function that returns that you should probably type the return value as `undefined` or just don't write silly undefined-casts :-)

Comment: @mpen My bad. It's true that void in `void 0` is an operator. BTW, typing the return value as `void` is exactly the same as `(): undefined`, and a function returns `undefined` does not make sense. Is it right?

Comment: @Ryuujo They're semantically different. If a function claims it returns `undefined` then the caller can rely on it returning `undefined`. If the function says it returns `void` then the caller shouldn't use the return value at all and none of their code should break if the return type is changed from `void` to `boolean` because they had no dependencies on the return value. This allows for backwards-compatible changes if everyone follows the contract.

Answer (score 11):

Also, for more a *theorical* reason, with `--strictNullChecks` new flag, TypeScript needed a new bottom type (since `null` and `undefined` are no more). The type `never` is such a bottom type and make TypeScript's type system more consistent.

Answer (score 9):

**Never** is information that this particular part shouldn't be reachable. For example in this code,

```
function do(): never {
    while (true) {}
}
```

you have an infinite loop and we don't want to iterate infinite loop. Simply as that.

But a real question is how can it be useful for us?
It might be helpful for instance while creating more advanced types to point **what they are not**

for example, let's declare our own NonNullable type:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Here we are checking if T is null or undefined. If it is then we are pointing that it should never happen. Then while using this type:

```
let value: NonNullable<string>;
value = "Test";
value = null; // error
```

**Void** is information that functions with this type don't return any value, but they are reachable and they can be used.

Comment: Bad example; `let value: NonNullable<string>;` is literally just `let value: string;`

Comment: Bad TS practice: if you passed type `string` to your `NonNullable<T>`, the type is inferred as `T` which is `string` definitely. so it's super duper the same as `let value: string;` !!

Answer (score 7):

The type never means that nothing occurs. It is used when a type guard cannot occur, or in a situation where an exception is always thrown. There is a difference between void and never. A function that has the explicit return type of never won’t allow returning undefined, which is different from a void function which allows returning undefined.

```
function functionThrow(): never {
throw new Error("This function return never");
```

}

For example, in the code below, there is an enum with two items. TypeScript knows that only two cases are possible and the default (else) case cannot occur. This insight of TypeScript is perfect since the function return type only accepts string, and does not accept never. If in the future you add a new item from enum, (for example, a ChoiceC without adding a new case in the switch statement), then the code can call the unhandledChoice function which returns never.

```
 enum EnumWithChoices {
    ChoiceA,
    ChoiceB,
    ChoiceC,
}

function functionReturnStringFromEnum(c: EnumWithChoices): string {
    switch (c) {
        case EnumWithChoices.ChoiceA:
            return "A";
        case EnumWithChoices.ChoiceB:
            return "B";
        default:
            return unhandledChoiceFromEnum(c);
    }
}

function unhandledChoiceFromEnum(x: never): never {
    throw new Error("Choice not defined");
}
```

In the end, never indicates a state not meant to be. An exception is not expected behavior. An infinite loop in a function is not meant to be sustainable in a system, a condition that is never visited should not exist.

Answer (score 5):

The return type of `Promise.reject()` is `Promise<never>`, meaning "it is never resolved".

So if a function returns `Promise<never>`, I think it will return only errors. On the other hand, `Promise<void>` might be resolved without value.

Comment: Seems like this is not the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291341/typescript-generics-void-never-or-undefined

Answer (score 2):

Here's another difference:

```
let x: string|never = undefined; // error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
let y: string|void = undefined;  // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add examples.
One function that returns nothing just prints to console. Function with side effect.

**Correct definitions**

```
function WriteToConsole():void{
  console.log('console')
}

function WriteToConsole():any{
  console.log('console')
}
```

**Compile error**

```
function WriteToConsole():never{
  console.log('console')
}

function WriteToConsole():undefined{
  console.log('console')
}
```

***never*** type usually used when we have ***throw*** in the function

Comment: Having a throw statement in a function does not mean, that the function always returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

Void - function doesn't return anything or explicitly returns undefined.

Never - function never returns anything at all.