# TypeScript generics: void, never, or undefined?

Tags: typescript

Always wondering about this. So want to get a definite answer and set it to stone :)

What I want to do is to let the compiler/language service/reader knows that `T` should be nothing, empty, nada. I want to know which one (`void`, `never`, `undefined`) is the right / best one to use.

```
// to indicate there should be no props available
class MyComponent extends React.Component<???, any> { ... }

// showing the Promise should resolve to nothing
function foo(): Promise<???> { ... }
```

( let me know if you can think of other cases you need to think about using `void`, `never`, or `undefined` in generics and I can add them to this list )

Related questions:
[What is the difference between never and void in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910669/what-is-the-difference-between-never-and-void-in-typescript)

From the above link, and the answer from @mierion-hughes, `never` seems to be clear. So the remaining question is `void` vs `undefined`

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. I can declare `Promise<void>`, `Promise<never>` and `Promise<undefined>` without any issue. Are you asking *which one to use*?? A promise does not ever resolve to "nothing". If no specific value is provided, then it resolves to `undefined`, and this works with any of the 3 options above.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking which one to use. Also, in the example above, the type system infer it to `{}` thus the error.

Comment: I'm running tsc 2.1.4 but I do not get the error you report getting. For this question to be up to the standards of this site, please post a [mcve]. (No screenshots but actual code.) Make sure to read the documentation on MCVEs and follow the instructions there. My own tests show that any of `void`, `never` and `undefined` work so be aware that your question may still be opinion-based once you put an actual MCVE in it.

Comment: I am also running 2.1.4. Updated the question with the code in screen shot

Comment: Don't post *fragments* of code. A [mcve] is supposed to be *complete* so post a *complete* example and show the output of running `tsc` on it. Include your `tsconfig.json`. People reading your question need to be able to replicate exactly the behavior you get. Otherwise, what you get instead of an actual answer are comments and stuff like the "I don't think this is a good answer" post that you got.

Comment: What about export class Foo<T = never>?

Comment: That is saying the type `T` defaults to `never`. It can still be anything if you specify it.

Answer (score 2):

*I don't think this is a good answer, but your question is a little vague anyway.*

I think the closest you'll get is to make the constructor argument optional T and use `never` or `void`.

[image]

the problem here is that using `void` or `never` both end up as `undefined` on the argument type. So... you can still pass `undefined`, and I cannot see a way to stop that.

Taking it a little further: If you don't want the property added to the instance, then you would need to drop the `public` on the arg:

```
class Foo<T>{
  prop: T;
  constructor(prop?: T) {
    if (prop != undefined)
      this.prop = prop;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo<never>(undefined);

for (let key in foo) {
  console.log(key); //prints: nothing
}

console.log(foo);  //prints:  Foo {}
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I couldn't see your answer until now. I checked a few times yesterday and only once I saw your answer popped up, but after that, it is gone (until now).  The use case you show is interesting, I never thought of that before. Do you know of any actual use case for such usage? I can't think of any :).

Comment: Also, in this case, what is the difference between `void` and `never`?

Comment: I deleted it originally... I may do again now you'd updated your question. it allows you to specify functions/promise that `never` return vs returning nothing (`void`).

Comment: I think it is good. I learn something new from it. Please keep it. :)