# Typescript overriding abstract method which is void return

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, abstract-methods

```
abstract class Base{
    abstract sayHello(): void;
}

class Child extends Base{
    sayHello() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

Abstract method's return type is **void** but I can implement it with a number type return.
I did not take any error from compiler. Is this kind of bug in Typescript?

[TS Spec](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void)

> The Void type, referenced by the void keyword, represents the absence
>   of a value and is used as the return type of functions with no return
>   value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind this is because the type system in typescript works on a structural type system. The idea of types is sort of like "contracts" where rules are set to say certain types are compatible with certain types. The compiler will only error if the contract is broken.
So for example:

```js
abstract class Base{
    abstract sayHello(): void;
}

class Child extends Base{
    sayHello(): number {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

This works because even though our method returns number when we implement it everything that uses `sayHello()` and expects it to return a void will have no side effect, no contracts are being broken. This is simply because Microsft set a rule in typescript saying the void return type is compatible with the number return type. The reason is as I said before it has no side effects, everything that expects `sayHello()` to return void should still work as expected.

On the other hand, if I did something like so:

```js
abstract class Base{
    abstract sayHello(): number;
}

class Child extends Base{
    sayHello(): void {
        return;
    }
}
```

This will error, because now everything that uses `sayHello()` and expects it to be a number will be affected, the contract of types has been broken making the compiler error.

You can look at this as a feature in flexibility in the type system at the trade-off for accidental type equivalence.

In a language like C# that uses a nominal type system, it will not allow us to have an abstract void method that when implemented returns a string as it has a focus on type equivalence, the types must be the same to be compatible with each other.

Hope this helps!

Structural type system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system

Nominal type system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system

Typescript Type Compatibility: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Spec: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3114-assignment-compatibility

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I glanced over your reference links. But they are not clear or too complex for me. We already have 'any' type to sign a function to return anything and we know that all functions return 'undefined' even if they don't have  return statement. So we can use 'undefined' instead of 'void'. There is no purpose for void it is just insane and mind burner.

Answer (score 1):

I [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37911102/3617380) Ryan Cavanaugh lead dev of TS:

> The return value of a function reference whose return type is void can be anything because it's legal for a non-void-returning function to be aliased by a void-returning type.

So the thing is about a *type* of function that returns `void`, can accept (be assigned) a *value* of function that returns anything.

```
type ReturnVoid = () => void

const foo: ReturnVoid = () => 42  // all good
```

This behavior is spec’ed in [Assignment Compatibility](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3114-assignment-compatibility) section

> M is a non-specialized call or construct signature and S has an apparent call or construct signature N where, [...] **the result type of M is Void**, or the result type of N is assignable to that of M

References:

1. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void
2. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21674

Comment: I got it bu it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It makes sense to me. Return void practically  means the return value can be safely ignored. So it shouldn’t matter if I return nothing or anything.

Comment: Also consider event handler. `.on(“click”, e => void)` most of time the callback signature returns void. What if I have a ready-made function that returns boolean, but it can work as this event handler, just the signature is a bit off? I wouldn’t want TS yell at me if I pass it in.

Comment: I think Typescript specification is not clear about that.
_The Void type, referenced by the void keyword, represents the absence of a value and is used as the return type of functions with no return value._

Comment: However, `Child.sayHello` does get typed to `number`? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgbwCgFiFRIZ4ExgBPACR2WQHsAKASgC4EA3ZgSwAmAbgIBfAgRRoMAYQAW-ZIIQ4AHhBwA7QRmxgcCQiSq0GTNuyNETJKDggBXKFoQBGAEwBmUSYkSpZi1IXmBkR0MAXgQtHAB3BAUlQQ4AOmp6RhYOBAAqBA8CIA)

Comment: Add references to answer. Hope it helps. I’m not on TS team and there’s not much I can do to convince you this behavior makes sense. TS team just pick a side and make this “by design”. And so it happens that I am personally happy with this result.