# TypeScript: function type derive， why type d is true?

Tags: typescript, extends

> look the function args  `a`  is not extends type  `never` . but the extends judge is true, why this happen?

```
type d = ((a: string) => void) extends ((b: never) => void) ? true : false;
let e: d = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

`never` is something called the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type). It is an empty set. And empty set can fit inside any other set (such as string in your example).

As the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) states:

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself).

In typescript `never` is used for a function that never returns.

I also recommend reading on [differences between void and never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910669/what-is-the-difference-between-never-and-void-in-typescript) in TypeScript.

Comment: yes . never fit inside any other set : ` never extends string` is true ..  no type is subtyoe of never so `string extends never` is false..     so  (a: string) => void) extends ((b: never) => void) , the function query string extends never ??? is should be false

Comment: I see your point. A function that expects a `never` parameter can't be invoked. Hence any parameter extending it is fine with TS.